# Should a view on your own question be counted as a view?

Tags: feature-request, bug

I apologize if this has already been brought up before but I am having trouble understanding the following:

If I view my own question on SO by refreshing it or coming back to it later, why should the view number go up?  I sometimes use that number to determine if the question is too general or obscure.  If I have high views but no interaction then it's clear to me I need to do something extra for clarification.

However, every time I go to check the question, it appears as though the view number is incremented by my own view.  To me, this is not a feature.

As mentioned in the comments below apparently it takes some time before the view on your own question is incremented.

Ultimately as some have pointed out, this is not a big deal.  And indeed I am inclined to agree.  But the point of this is to try and improve the user experience, is it not?  This would be a trivial and minor, yet helpful improvement, in my opinion.

Comment: *"If I view my own question on SO (...), why should the view number go up?"* ... *"If I view my own question"* ... *"If I view"* ... *"view"* ... views++;   (I get where you're coming from but you can always just estimate how often you've visited and subtract that from the shown number). I wouldn't consider this a bug.

Comment: If you get where I am coming from then the sarcasm wasn't necessary.  Yes I can add and subtract - however I am suggesting a change that I think would add to the website's overall usability.

Comment: IIRC you don't count as another view for 15 minutes.  IMHO it's not something to worry about.

Comment: @Matt1776 You'll just get people wondering why the system says their question hasn't been viewed even though they know it has been viewed (something that happens already on occasion when the view counter hasn't updated yet).  And how is you having a less accurate view count more useful for you?  It not like you don't know that you've viewed your question, and it's not like the view counter is actually accurate to that precise of a value anyway.  Your own views is basically always within the margin of error of the view counter (because that margin of error is *super* high.

Comment: Apparently this is a duplicate question - I did not phrase it the right way for it to come up in a search but I've put in a request to close it.  Rather than delete it because I still feel changing this would be an improvement and I want my post to be recorded.  If that's even how it works.

Comment: @Matt1776 I was really just trying to point out that you tagged this question as "bug" as well, whereas it seems to me like you actually only wanted to propose a change instead of pointing out that something's accidentally broken.

Comment: @Keiwan point taken.  But, I will point out that what is a bug and what is a feature is sometimes a point of view.  Tell that to the QA people I've worked with :)